# Since then and ever since | verb tense

Tags: grammar

Are the verbs tenses in these two sentences, and the grammar, correct?

> This is Ivanka. She quit smoking years ago and **since then** with the money she used to buy cigarettes, she now buys food for Dubrovnik's cat.
>
> This is Ivanka. **Ever since** she quit smoking, with the money she used to buy cigarettes, she has bought food for Dubrovnik's cat.

Comment: These are OK. You could use lots of others and lots of other constructions, of course, but these are OK. But there should be a comma after _since then_.

Comment: Lots of other construction? Can you please give me an example?

Comment: It depends on how much you want to cram into one sentence. It doesn't cost more to use two sentences if you have enough information.

Comment: "money she used" could more precisely be "money she used to use" or "money she would have used"

Comment: Do you think this is more accurate : Since she quit smoking, years ago, with the money she would have used to buy cigarettes, she now buys food for Dubrovnik's cat.

Comment: Don't you think both examples are too obviously artificial constructs? Won't the Question become more clear if you drop the excess detail, as in 'Ivanka quit smoking and since then with the money she's saved, she's been buying food'? Other constructs are readily available but neither of the choices given is desirable.

Comment: Either is fine, but the first emphasises what she does now and the second what she has done in the recent past.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences are better put this way

> This is Ivanka. She quit smoking years ago and **since then** with the money she used to buy cigarettes, she "has" been buying food for Dubrovnik's cat.
>
> This is Ivanka. **Ever since** she quit smoking, with the money she used to buy cigarettes, she "has" been buying food for Dubrovnik's cat.

"has" can be replaed with "had". "An action (presumably recurring)" "from then till now" goes better with "past" or "present" perfect continuous. Other options are use  of "simple past" or "simple present". "now" is unnecessary and it raises the question "what was she doing before now (with the money she saved by not smoking)?".

Usage of "past perfect" and "present perfect" would mean the buying of food may be a recurring, not-recurring, one-time or sporadic action.